# jQuery, Target HTML generated dynamically

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress, prettyphoto

I'm trying to add/remove classes with jQuery to HTML elements generated by JavaScript dynamically. More specifically, to prettyPhoto's HTML in a WordPress theme. I need to add/remove a class to prettyPhoto's main parent div based on the class of a deep child link. This class gets changed by prettyPhoto. And all this HTML appears only when you click on an image on the page. I don't want to fiddle with the actual prettyPhoto script (included in the theme core files), so trying to do it with a jQuery function.

The HTML generated is (roughly) like this:

```
<div pp_pic_holder>
  <1st level child>
      ...
            <6th level child>
              <a pp_expand>
```

And my current js is like this:

```
<script>
jQuery( 'body' ).on('change', 'div.pp_pic_holder', function() {
    jQuery( "a.pp_expand" ).parents( "div.pp_pic_holder" ).addClass( "contracted" ).removeClass( "expanded" );
    jQuery( "a.pp_contract" ).parents( "div.pp_pic_holder" ).addClass( "expanded" ).removeClass( "contracted" );
});
</script>
```

This doesn't work. I've tried with different options with `.on` and `.live` following examples from about 15 similar questions here on Stack Overflow, but nothing... I almost don't know js, so reading through the event delegation documentation only broke my brain.
Please help.
Thank you!

**UPD:**
Thanks to @Pete for his suggestions.
The code that finally made this work is this:

```
<script>
jQuery( 'body' ).on( 'DOMSubtreeModified', function() {
    jQuery( "a.pp_expand" ).closest( "div.pp_pic_holder" ).addClass( "contracted" ).removeClass( "expanded" );
    jQuery( "a.pp_contract" ).closest( "div.pp_pic_holder" ).addClass( "expanded" ).removeClass( "contracted" );
});
</script>
```

Comment: @Pete Tried that. Maybe code was wrong somewhere. I'm a newb in js.

Comment: **There's no event that does what you're wanting.** You should instead use/add a callback to whatever is changing the html.

Comment: Are you able to provide a link to your working site for us to inspect?  I don't believe your current JS is valid.

Comment: Do you get an errors in the console? Could you try something like this just to see if the event is triggered `$('body').on('change',  function(event) {
    var target = $( event.target );  
    if ( target.is( "div.pp_pic_holder" ) ) {  
        alert('Target div');
    } 
});`

Comment: @GlenDespaux Sure. Here's an example - http://houseofthenobleman.com/project/nathaniel-rackowe-portal/

Comment: *"I don't want to fiddle with the actual prettyPhoto script"* That sounds like you're only option, unless you're willing to break down and use a setInterval that repeatedly checks for said elements... which is pretty poor design.

Comment: @JNewton Tried just now. Nothing.

Comment: @KevinB - any chance of having the function sit there and automatically apply each time said HTML is generated?

Comment: @somepaulo that's what the setInterval idea does. very inefficiently of course. *something* has to call the function.

Comment: I'm impressed by the amount of classes tacked on to `html` and `body`. Also, I honestly don't see where this can reasonably be achieved.

Comment: @somepaulo that would suggest the event is not being triggered, `$('body').on('change', function(event) { 
  alert('Target body');  
});` move the alert out of the `if` statement and see if it gets called, this could make @Pete suggestion correct and that an `.on('change'` event is never triggered.

Comment: @somepaulo, I think you want to use DOMSubtreeModified (case sensitive) event - see my edited answer

Comment: @Pete Thanks for the suggestions, but none of them works.

Comment: @Pete Thanks again for the suggestions. I managed to cook up a working solution from your examples.